# How to return an apache error page from a wsgi app?

Tags: python, apache, wsgi

I have a simple working wsgi app. I can successfully return whatever HTTP status code, headers, and HTML I want. What I would like to do, is that when I'm returning a status code *other* than '200 OK', for WSGI to let apache fall back to its error handling and display whatever page apache is configured to display according to its 'ErrorDocument' setting.

For example, this works fine when my WSGI app crashes unintentionally, then I see the default 'internal server error' page from apache.

My question is, how can I do this in a controlled, deliberate manner? For example, I can then do my own authentication, and fallback to the default apache page I have set up.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presuming you actually mean with mod_wsgi under Apache, ensure you are using mod_wsgi daemon mode and set:

```
WSGIErrorOverride On
```

There is a brief mention of this in mod_wsgi version 3.0 release notes.

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ChangesInVersion0300

If you are using Apache as proxy in front of distinct Python web server running WSGI application, then use Apache ProxyErrorOverride directive instead.

Comment: I have the same issue and the WSGIErrorOverride On does not work for me

Comment: Are you confident you are using mod_wsgi daemon mode. Verify it with http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation#Embedded_Or_Daemon_Mode