# Why isn't my custom Apache error page showing?

Tags: apache, mod-wsgi

I have a mod_wsgi application running under Apache2, and whenever there is an uncaught exception, the default Apache HTTP 500 error page is shown despite the fact that I have `ErrorDocument 500 /500.html` in my Apache config.

Is there some mod_wsgi directive I can use to display my custom error page? I'm not looking for something I can put in my mod_wsgi script as that won't help if there is an error in the script.

**Edit 2:** When using the below configuration browsing to `/cgi-bin/test.wsgi` displays the custom error page successfully, but browsing to `/test` displays the default Apache one.

**Edit:** Here is a small sample configuration that gives me the same problem:

**/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/test**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName foo.example.com

    DocumentRoot /path/to/docroot/

    <Directory /path/to/docroot/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /path/to/docroot/cgi-bin/

    <Directory /path/to/docroot/cgi-bin/>
        Options +ExecCGI
        AddHandler wsgi-script .wsgi
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorDocument 500 /500.html

    WSGIDaemonProcess test user=www-data group=www-data processes=4 threads=1 display-name=%{GROUP}
    WSGIProcessGroup test
</VirtualHost>
```

**/path/to/docroot/.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^test/?$    /cgi-bin/test.wsgi/    [L,QSA]
```

**/path/to/docroot/500.html**

```
<html><body>This be 500.</body></html>
```

**/path/to/docroot/cgi-bin/test.wsgi**

```
hi
```

Answer (score 0):

What does the URL /500.html map to with the Apache configuration used?

If it doesn't map to a valid URL and so an attempt to issue a sub request against it generates a 404, then Apache will thence return a generic 500 response.

Have a look in your access log for the /500.html access and see if it indicates a 404.

Comment: Nope, no 404s in any of the logs, and the `500.html` is located in the `DocumentRoot` which is specified before the `ErrorDocument`. I've tried changing the `ErrorDocument` to an absolute URL but that doesn't work either.

Comment: But if you have WSGIScriptAlias for / then that overrides and hides DocumentRoot. You need to use Alias /500.html /some/path/foo.html

Comment: I'm not using `WSGIScriptAlias`, and adding an `Alias` directly to the file doesn't work either.

Comment: Then how have you configured mod_wsgi to host your WSGI application?

Comment: `WSGIDaemonProcess`, `AddHandler wsgi-script`, and `.htaccess`.

Comment: Add if you actually point your browser at /500.html does it work? And which configuration file is the ErrorDocument directive in? Best to put the all the actual configuration lines related to this in your question rather than letting me guess exactly what they are set to and where you put them. Do you even have a WSGIProcessGroup for example which is supposed to be paired with WSGIDaemonProcess.

Comment: I can access /500.html by pointing my browser at is, yes. I've updated the question with an Apache config that gives me the same problem.

Comment: If you are trying to remap an existing 500 error page generated from the WSGI application to a site wide one setup in Apache you must when using daemon mode set the directive "WSGIErrorOverride On".

Comment: I've added that directive but it doesn't appear to solve the problem. Oddly enough visiting `/cgi-bin/test.wsgi` displays the custom document but `/test` displays Apache's default one.

Comment: Don't use a RewriteRule. If you really don't want to use WSGIScriptAlias, use MultiViewsMatch to get rid of extension. http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationGuidelines#The_Apache_Alias_Directive

Comment: That's not an option for the website that has this problem. There are several hundred rules in the `.htaccess` file, a lot which need to stay for legacy reasons. It's not that I want `test` to go to `test.wsgi`, I might also want `/purple/dragons` and `/supertest` to go to `test.wsgi`.

Comment: Also, following the instructions on the same page that you linked to mount a wsgi script at the root of the site has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

By default the WSGI application takes complete control over the request *and* response cycle, so any Apache error handlers will be bypassed.

You will likely need a `WSGIErrorOverride On` directive before the Apache settings work. I have not tried this myself yet, but in tracking down advice on a similar goal for an ops team (having Apache return its own static error page when a Django app gives a 500) I came across this via [How to return an apache error page from a wsgi app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691204/how-to-return-an-apache-error-page-from-a-wsgi-app) and — with the opposite goal — [How to configure Apache with mod_wsgi so that error messages come from the application?](https://serverfault.com/questions/581410/how-to-configure-apache-with-mod-wsgi-so-that-error-messages-come-from-the-appli).

The [original description](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/issues/detail?id=57) for this feature as it was being added to mod_wsgi was:

> In the case of mod_proxy there exists the ProxyErrorOverride directive,
>   which allows one to say that you want error pages generated by the back end
>   application to be ignored when appropriate, and allow Apache to generate
>   the content through its normal ErrorDocument directives.
>
> An equivalent WSGIErrorOverride directive should be implemented to allow
>   WSGI applications to be better fitted into a large site where the WSGI
>   application isn't the only source of content, but just one contributor.

So it does sound like what we are after. Note that this was added to mod_wsgi version 3.0 and later, which have hopefully been out long enough to be in common use.

Comment: Just keep in mind that WSGIErrorOverride only works if using mod_wsgi daemon mode.